.Net 8 Blazor "extract block to code behind" also adds file to different project in the same solution
I have a bunch of components in my .Net 8 Blazor SSR application that I originally developed using the @code block. I've started extracting these to code behind files but when I use the built-in refactoring (Extract block to code behind), the .cs file gets created in the folder it should, but it is also created in the root of the neighboring project in the solution. This project happens to be a database project.
